# how to return a couple of value from a querySelector?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get an object with the value and the inner text from a dropDown menu using a query selector:

```html
<label>
  <span>Project :</span>
</label>
<select name="projectId">
  <option value="1">foo</option>
  <option value="2">bar</option>
</select>
```

I want an object that look like this:

```
{
    "1":"foo",
    "2":"bar"
}
```

here's where I come from

```js
let options = await page.evaluate(() => {
                return document.querySelector('select[name=projectId]').innerText;
            });
```

but I only get a string of the inner text I can't figure out how to achieve my goal, can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let options = await page.evaluate(() => {

  // Get all option items
  const options =  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('select[name=projectId] option'));
  // Iterate through all option items and set corresponding object properties
  return options.reduce((acc, item) => {
    return {...acc, ...{[item.value]: item.innerText}}
  }, {})

});
```

Comment: You can use `item.value` instead of `item.getAttribute('value')`

Comment: True, i changed it, thx

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get all the option elements, spread syntax to convert it to an array, [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to extract the value and text of each option, and [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to convert it to a single object.

```js
const res = Object.fromEntries(
  [...document.querySelectorAll("select[name=projectId] > option")]
    .map(o => [o.value, o.text]));
console.log(res);
```

```html
<label>
  <span>Project :</span>
</label>
<select name="projectId">
  <option value="1">foo</option>
  <option value="2">bar</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thank you but in my case I'm using puppeteer and it return an error saying document is not defined

Comment: @lolozen All of the answers here use `document` in some way. The code in your question also uses `document.querySelector`.

Comment: okay so I need to get the document from my 'page'

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get multiple elements via a query selector, you can use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). It looks like you want to do something along these lines:

```js
const options = document.querySelectorAll('[name="projectId"] option');

const optionData = {};
for (let option of options) {
  optionData[option.value] = option.innerText;
}

console.log(optionData);
```

```html
<label>
  <span>Project :</span>
</label>
<select name="projectId">
  <option value="1">foo</option>
  <option value="2">bar</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

simply ?

```js
console.log( 
  Object.fromEntries(
  Array.from(
    document.querySelector('select[name=projectId]').options
    ,el=>[el.value,el.textContent] 
) ) )
```

```html
<select name="projectId">
  <option value="1">foo</option>
  <option value="2">bar</option>
</select>
```